# Inferred type is not a valid substitute for a Comparable generic type

Tags: java, generics, collections

Consider the code:

```
public abstract class Item<T> implements Comparable<T>
{
    protected T item;

    public int compareTo(T o)
    {
        return 0; // this doesn't matter for the time being
    }
}

public class MyItem<T> extends Item<String>
{
    T object;
}

public class Foo<T>
{
    protected ArrayList<T> list;
}

public class Bar<V> extends Foo<MyItem<V>>
{
    public void sort()
    {
        Collections.sort(list);
    }
}
```

The sort call gives the error:

> Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List< T >) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList< MyItem< T > >). The inferred type MyItem< T > is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter < T extends Comparable< ? super T > >

Why is this wrong?

If `MyItem<V>` implements `Comparable` then why is it not a substitute?

Sorry if this has been asked, but I feel the question is somewhat specific.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually more detailed explanation of this error gives your `javac` itself:

> java: no suitable method found for `sort(java.util.ArrayList<MyItem<V>>`)
>
> method `java.util.Collections.<T>sort(java.util.List<T>,java.util.Comparator<?
>   super T>)` is not applicable (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>
> method `java.util.Collections.<T>sort(java.util.List<T>)` is not applicable (inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s) inferred: `MyItem<V>` bound(s): `java.lang.Comparable<? super MyItem<V>>`)

So, the main question is:
**why is method `Collections.<T>sort(java.util.List<T>)`) not applicable?**

**The answer is**:
because in `Collections.<T>sort(java.util.List<T>)` method declaration there are bounds on parameter `T`: `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`.

In another words, `T` must implement `Comparable` interface on it self. For example `String` class implements such interface: `...implements ...  Comparable<String>`.

In your case `Item` class doesn't implement such interface:

`Item<T> implements Comparable<T>` is not same thing as `Item<T> implements Comparable<Item<T>>`.

So, for solving this problem, your should change your `Item` class to this one:

```
public abstract class Item<T> implements Comparable<Item<T>>
{
    protected T item;

    public int compareTo(Item<T> o)
    {
        return 0; // this doesn't matter for the time being
    }
}
```

Comment: That was spot on. Cheers! For clarification, I included the extra classes because the code I provided is a much more simplified version of my actual code, and I wasn't sure where the problem was. I completely missed that I could just change the actual comparison itself. Thanks again.

Comment: Better : `public abstract class Item<T> implements Comparable<? extends Item<T>>` - no ?

Answer (score 2):

For objects of type `X` to be comparable with each other, class `X` has to implement exactly `Comparable<X>`.

This is not what your code is doing, you've got a class `Item<T>` and you are implementing `Comparable<T>` instead of `Comparable<Item<T>>`. This means that `Item<T>` can be compared with `T`, but not with `Item<T>`, which is required.

Change your `Item<T>` class to:

```
public abstract class Item<T> implements Comparable<Item<T>>
{
    protected T item;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item<T> o)
    {
        return 0; // this doesn't matter for the time being
    }
}
```

Comment: "For objects of type X to be comparable with each other, class X has to implement exactly Comparable<X>." Not necessarily exactly. X could implement `Comparable<SomeSuperTypeOfX>`

Answer (score 1):

Just change the class like follow:

```
     public class MyItem<T> extends Item<String> implement Comparable<MyItem<T>>
     {
         T object;
     }
```

Or

```
       public abstract class Item<T> implements Comparable<MyItem<T>>
       {
           protected T item;

           public int compareTo(MyItem<T> o)
           {
              return 0; // this doesn't matter for the time being
       }
```

}

The error tips has shown us.Hope it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have the class `MyItem` generified just to see the effect. The following class is enough to see what happens:

```
public class MyItem extends Item<String> {}
```

Now you have the following call:

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

As morgano stated correctly, the sort method will take a collection that is parameterized with a type T that must be comparable to T. Your `MyItem` class is extending `Item<String>`, which results in `MyItem` being comparable to `String`s.

With a little switch in which class implements the `Comparable` interface, you will get the expected result:

```
public abstract class Item<T> {
    protected T item;
}

public class MyItem extends Item<String> implements Comparable<MyItem> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(MyItem o) {
        return item.compareTo(o.item); // just an example
    }
}
```

And now the call to `Collections.sort(list)` will work.