# java calling a generic static method

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to make a generic method to compare objects from many types.

This is my simple interface

```
interface comparable<T> {
    boolean isBiggerThan(T t1);
}
```

and this is one implementation for it:

```
class StringComparable implements comparable<String> {

    public StringComparable(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    String s;

    @Override
    public boolean isBiggerThan(String t1) {
        return s.equals(t1);
    }

}
```

this is my class that has a generic method:

```
class Utilt {
    public static <T extends comparable<T>> int biggerThan(T values[], T t) {
        int count = 0;
        for (T oneValue : values) {
            if (oneValue.isBiggerThan(t)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

I call that method like this:

```
public class TestTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StringComparable a = new StringComparable("Totti");
        StringComparable pi = new StringComparable("Pirlo");
        int i = Utilt.biggerThan(new StringComparable[] { a, pi }, a);
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
The method `biggerThan(T[], T)` in the type `Utilt` is not applicable for the arguments `(StringComparable[], StringComparable)`
```

Comment: refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739720/inferred-type-is-not-a-valid-substitute-for-a-comparable-generic-type

Answer (score 1):

The generic parameter `T` of your static method `biggerThan` must implement `comparable<T>`. `StringComparable` implements `comparable<String>`, not `comparable<StringComparable>`, so it doesn't match your static method's generic parameter.

You can fix this by changing `StringComparable` to implement `comparable<StringComparable>`.

```
class StringComparable implements comparable<StringComparable> {

    public StringComparable(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    String s;

    @Override
    public boolean isBiggerThan(StringComparable t1) {
        return s.equals(t1.s);
    }

}
```

After making that change, your `main` would pass compilation and print `1`.

That said, I'm not sure how much sense it makes for a method that tests of equality to be called `isBiggerThan`.

Comment: but that is not what i want to do, i want the comparable interface to with string not with stringComparable

Answer (score 0):

Your comparator interface is expecting a String value and not String array. While when calling that method, you are passing StringComparable array so its showing the error

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that `!comparable<String> instanceof comparable<StringComparable>`.
So try something like this:

```
class StringComparable implements comparable<StringComparable> {

  public StringComparable(String s) {
    this.s = s;
  }

  String s;

  public String getS(){
    return s;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isBiggerThan(StringComparable t1) {
    return s.equals(t1.getS());
  }

}
```

And Utilt class

```
class Utilt {
    public static <T extends comparable<T>> int biggerThan(T values[], T t) {
        int count = 0;
        for (T oneValue : values) {
            if (oneValue.isBiggerThan(t)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Also is better to override `equals` and `hashCode`, so you can call `this.equals(t1)` in `isBiggerThan` method.

BTW, method `isBiggerThan` looks very suspicious as long as:

```
StringComparable s1 = new StringComparable("string1");
StringComparable s2 = new StringComparable("string2");
s1.isBiggerThan(s2); // output => true
s2.isBiggerThan(s1); // output => true
```

It's up to you, but for me this logic looks wrong.